# Angular filter expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I'm working on a filter expression that filters by the data-ID of an element.

The problem I'm having is that the filter will return multiple values if other ID's have the same digits positioned elsewhere (i.e. filter **12** RETURNS **12**, **12**3, **12**34). I'd like to just return the one element with the exact value of 12.

JS

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.customers = [
  {
    id: 12,
    name: 'customer 1 - 1'
  },
  {
    id: 123,
    name: 'customer 2 - 12'
  },
  {
    id: 1234,
    name: 'customer 3 - 12'
  }

];
});
```

HTML

```
Filter: <input ng-model="filterCustomer" />
<hr/>
<select size="4" ng-options="customer as customer.name for customer in customers | filter:{id: filterCustomer} track by customer.id" ng-model="customerSelection">
</select>
```

I've also tried adding the following expression to the filter to match digit length... but it's not working as expected

```
filter:{id:filterFsaisCustomer.toString().length}
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/iYfwrTFzz10il7rC0zDS?p=preview) is a Plunker.

Answer (score 1):

It should be used as strict checking by adding `true` inside your filter, also you should have convert the value in `integer` just by making input field to `type="number"` will parse that to `int`.

**Markup**

```
<input type="number" ng-model="filterCustomer" />

<select size="4" 
  ng-options="customer as customer.name for customer in customers | filter:{id: filterCustomer}:true track by customer.id" 
  ng-model="customerSelection">
</select>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/rluJ7JksguzyjtCITzkA?p=preview)

**Edit**

To enable filter only after value entered in textbox then it would become conditional base strict checking `| filter:{id:  filterCustomer}:filterCustomer>0`

```
<select size="4" 
  ng-options="customer as customer.name for customer in customers | filter:{id:  filterCustomer}:filterCustomer>0  track by customer.id" 
  ng-model="customerSelection">
</select>
```

[**Updated Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/R1Vow4fj45wvLSMSFyqb?p=preview)

Comment: this works but breaks if a value is cleared from the input

Comment: @Kyle.Belanger take a look at updated plunkr and answer